# Getting overflow:hidden to work in IE7

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-7, overflow

Anyone know how to get this to work in IE7?

The images are displayed side by side (due to overflow) instead of as a slider.

http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/PortfolioZoomSlider/

I tried setting `overflow:hidden` on the `.thumb_wrapper` but part of the next slide still shines through and covers the arrow.

Comment: Don't know if it's related, but maybe you should have a look at http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Ftympanus.net%2FTutorials%2FPortfolioZoomSlider%2F

Comment: Seem to be mostly unrelated validation errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `position: relative;` to your `.thumb` declaration in your style.css file.  The IE7 layout engine won't enforce `overflow: hidden;` without some sort of position rule.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
.thumb_wrapper A.next, .thumb_wrapper A.prev{
    *display:block;
    *z-index:10000;
    *background-color:red;
    *top:15px;
    *background-position:left center;
    *height:100%;
    *width:40px;
}

.thumb_wrapper{
    *overflow:hidden;
}
```

at the end of all your styles.

Comment: Was no need, as the solution by the other user worked (adding position: relative to .thumb) -- thanks though!